# uid not getting saved in firebase database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native

```
import React from 'react'
import firebase from 'firebase';

const config = {
  apiKey: "***",
  authDomain: "***",
  databaseURL: "***",
  projectId: "***",
  storageBucket: "***",
  messagingSenderId: "***",
  appId: "***",
  measurementId: "***"
};

const fire = firebase.initializeApp(config);

export default class SignUp extends React.Component {

  state = { email: '', password: '', userName: '', errorMessage: null };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  handleSignUp = () => {
    const { userName, email, password } = this.state;
    firebase.
      auth()
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password)
      .then(authUser => {
        this.props.fire.database().ref('/users/')
          .child(authUser.user.uid)
          .set({
            userName,
            email,
          });
      })
      .then(() => this.props.navigation.navigate('message'))
      .catch(error => this.setState({ errorMessage: error.message }))
  }
}
```

my db is not getting updated with username and email.

1.New with database handling and react so mostly
 must be using database functions incorrectly

2.Please check handlesignup function

3.Data of firebase authentication is getting update properly
uid and user mail are displayed properly

4.part where uid is saved which is not working

```
.then(authUser => {
   this.props.fire.database().ref('/users/')
      .child(authUser.user.uid)
      .set({
        userName,
        email,
      });
  })
```

Comment: Hello, what is `fire` (`import fire from '../fire';`)?

Comment: i have updated the code

Comment: @boop_the_snoot  Thank you, I'll  be careful next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do

```
firebase.auth()
```

you should similarly do

```
firebase.database().ref('/users/')
      .child(authUser.user.uid)
      .set({...})
```

since `firebase` is "a global namespace from which all Firebase services are accessed", see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase